# How to use Dates.Format with locale in Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm trying to format a date with locale in Thymeleaf, I already used the dates.format

```
<td th:text="${#dates.format(embargo.fecha, 'dd-MMMM-yyyy', new Locale('es'))}"></td>

<td th:text="${#dates.format(embargo.fecha, 'dd-MMMM-yyyy',${ new Locale('es')})}"></td>
```

but none of above works.

I was based in this issue that is already solved 
https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-java8time/pull/6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I stumble upon the same problem as you.

The reason is not working is because you need to use `#temporals` instead of `#dates`.

In order to do that, you need to add to your project the **thymeleaf-extras-java8time** dependency:

```
compile("org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-java8time:3.0.4.RELEASE")
```

Keep in mind that the **Locale** feature was added after the release of version 2.1.0 so you **MUST** be using Thymeleaf 3. Add:

```
compile("org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring4:3.0.6.RELEASE")
compile("org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf:3.0.6.RELEASE")
compile("nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-layout-dialect:2.2.2")
```

And as @Andreas pointed out, you need to specify the whole package name, for example:

```html
<td th:text="${#temporals.format(embargo.fecha, 'dd-MMMM-yyyy', new java.util.Locale('es', 'ES'))}"></td>
```

Also notice that the `#temporals` does not work with **java.util.Dates** and they do with **java.time.LocalDate** and **java.time.LocalDateTime**

If you can not change your backend to use **java.time.LocalDate** a solution would be to create it from you **java.util.Date**, using the static method `of(year, month, day)` from the **LocalDate** class.

For example:

```
T(java.time.LocalDate).of(#dates.year(embargo.fecha), #dates.month(embargo.fecha), #dates.day(embargo.fecha))
```

Putting that inside your example, it would become:

```html
<td th:text="${#temporals.format(T(java.time.LocalDate).of(#dates.year(embargo.fecha), #dates.month(embargo.fecha), #dates.day(embargo.fecha)), 'dd-MMMM-yyyy', new java.util.Locale('es', 'ES'))}"></td>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Thymeleaf with Spring Boot, the expressions are [SpEL](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions) (Spring Expression Language), and the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions-constructors) says:

> You can invoke constructors by using the `new` operator. You should **use the fully qualified class name** for all but the primitive types (`int`, `float`, and so on) and `String`.

So, you need to use `new java.util.Locale('es')` instead of just `new Locale('es')`

Comment: I'm using the next expression but it still does not work #dates.format(embargo.fecha, 'dd-MMMM-yyyy', new java.util.Locale('es')) does it need some importation?

Comment: @JulianSolarte You just say it doesn't work. Perhaps you should edit the question and explain *how* it doesn't work, e.g. show the full stack trace, if it's because an exception is thrown.

Comment: @Andreas Are you sure the expressions are SpEL? When I use invalid expressions, the exception mentions failing to parse an OGNL expression. And I can definitely use OGNL syntax successfully, like using `@java.util.Locale@ENGLISH` to use the pre-defined constant Locale.