# Is there a way to use #dates in Thymeleaf to only include day, month, and year while keeping locale formatting?

Tags: date, thymeleaf, locale

`<div th:text="${#dates.format(204587433443L)}"></div` gives

`June 25, 1976 5:50:33 PM EDT` in English, and

`25 juin 1976 17:50:33 EDT` in French

I would like only the day, month, and year while still keeping the language specific formatting like so:

`June 25, 1976` for English, and

`25 juin 1976` for French.

I have tried `<div th:text="${#dates.format(204587433443L, 'MMMM dd, yyyy')}"></div` but that results in `juin 25, 1976` which isn't what I want.

---

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Dates.Format with locale in Thymeleaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55245467/how-to-use-dates-format-with-locale-in-thymeleaf)

Answer (score 0):

you can use a switch condition for each Culture :

```
<div th:switch="${#locale}"> 
<p th:case="'en-US'">
   // us colture format MMMM dd YYYY
<p th:case="'fr-FR '">
  // us colture format dd MMMM YYYY
```